# Counting items by substrings in a Multiset in Java

Tags: java-stream

I have the following data in a guava Multiset.  Each item is the combined string of 3 items separated by a ':'.  I know all the values for each of the slots. I'm using the values to generate a data file for an interactive graph (by stuffing the split values into an object and then using Gson to print the object).

What's the best way to grab the cumulative count for all items that match just one, one:two, or one:two:three of the substrings?  I keep going round and round with streams, forEach, maps and filters, but can't seem to write an elegant set of loops.  Any suggestions or examples would be helpful.

Executive:Healthcare:United States x 5

Executive:Healthcare:Malaysia x 2

Executive:Financials:United States x 1

FinancialHealth:Technology:Malaysia x 3

FinancialHealth:Technology:United States x 2

FinancialHealth:Energy:United States x 1

Executive = 8

FinancialHealth = 6

Executive:Heathcare = 7

Executive:Financials = 1

FinancialHealth:Technology = 5

FinancialHealth:Energy = 1

Executive:Healthcare:United States = 5

etc.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams can help a great deal here, and it is not even difficult.
We need to take three steps in a stream:

```java
allTheStrings.stream()
                  // First, we will multiply each string "A:B:C" using `flatMap`
                  // so that the stream contains "A", "A:B", and "A:B:C":
             .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(":")),
                                     s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(":")),
                                     s))
                  // next, we are going to summarize multiple occurrences
                  // of the strings using a groupingBy collector:
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                 // This would return a Map<String, List<String>> containing each unique
                 // string mapped to its occurrences. But because you don't need the
                 // single occurrences, but instead just their number, we add a step
                 // to the collect which will make it return a Map<String, Long>
                                            Collectors.counting()))
```

---

So, as a full example:

```java
Stream.of("Executive:Healthcare:United States", "Executive:Healthcare:United States",
          "Executive:Healthcare:United States", "Executive:Healthcare:United States",
          "Executive:Healthcare:United States", "Executive:Healthcare:Malaysia",
          "Executive:Healthcare:Malaysia", "Executive:Financials:United States",
          "FinancialHealth:Technology:Malaysia", "FinancialHealth:Technology:Malaysia",
          "FinancialHealth:Technology:Malaysia", "FinancialHealth:Technology:United States",
          "FinancialHealth:Technology:United States", "FinancialHealth:Energy:United States")
      .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(":")), s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(":")), s))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
      .entrySet()
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will output

```java
Executive=8
Executive:Healthcare=7
FinancialHealth:Technology=5
FinancialHealth=6
FinancialHealth:Energy=1
FinancialHealth:Technology:Malaysia=3
FinancialHealth:Energy:United States=1
Executive:Healthcare:United States=5
Executive:Financials:United States=1
FinancialHealth:Technology:United States=2
Executive:Healthcare:Malaysia=2
Executive:Financials=1
```